# Logo of blender SE

Tags: feature-request

I notice that every major SE site has its own logo. I don't know who has the power to set a logo, but I think it would also be a nice promotion to do a blender SE logo contest in the blender artist forum or something like that.

Comment: this is a bit early.. besides we don't get a logo and fancy visuals until we graduate, however this is still valid and will be addressed when the time is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the site is about ready to graduate, the SE team will ask a question here on our meta looking for ideas about how the finished site will look. This will include the logo and graphic design. The team will design us a custom branding which will include the logo.

https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/400/24168 is one site's design suggestions and you can see how it turned out.

As I said, this will all be decided when we get closer to graduation, but it can't hurt to think about it now.

Comment: And now it has been posted: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/782/blender-site-design-ideas-input-welcome?cb=1

Answer (score 4):

I think we get a logo once Blender.SE is out of beta.